# Приложение Symfony CLI не видит расширения PHP 8.1

Tags: php, windows-10, openserver, extension

Есть проблема рабочей среды в `windows` для `symfony 6`.

Использую ՝openserver՝.

Те расширения которые должны быть, все установлены в `php` и включены в `php.ini`.

Но `Symfony` не хочет их видеть.

`php.ini` именно тот. После перезаписи `php.ini` сервер перезапущен полностью.

Вот пример : `openssl` подключен и виден в `phpinfo`. Но `Symfony` почему то не хочет работать с ним.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можете сказать как решить эту проблему?

Вот скриншоты для подробностей

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: FYI, Symfony не может "видеть" или "не видеть" расширения. Symfony - это код, написанный на РНР, и с расширениями работает РНР.

Comment: @Ипатьев Я знаю что это код написанный в `php`.  Но это целая система. Тогда зачем те же разширения работают нормально например на `Laravel`.

Comment: Вам уже ответили: **laravel использует другой php.ini**

Comment: @Ипатьев Ну скажите как испарвить ситуацию? Если знаете? И как по другому сформировать вопрос?

Comment: Наберите php -i и смотрите, какой файл php.ini используется в консольном РНР

Comment: @Ипатьев Тот же самый. ` C:\OpenServer\modules\php\PHP_8.1\php.ini`.

Comment: Понятно, вы говорите про Symfony Cli. Какая-то вещь в себе. Вообще это все конечно очень странно.  ну попробуйте набрать  `symfony local:php:list` хотя и так ясно, что он выведет тот же самый... Возможно, у вас где-то в PATH есть какой-то левый php.ini который эта заумная утилита цепляет первым